# Get attribute or content from list elements in unordered html list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I have a hidden unordered list with a number of list elements that I use to hold some information. Via JavaScript or jQuery I want to get the information of each of these list elements, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.
The list elements hold the information in the form of a string (e.g. 'text_1,2'), but it doesn't matter if it's its id, text or whatever, as long as the information is bound to that particular element.
Here's an example of what I've tried so far:

```
    var ul = document.getElementById('coordinateList');
    for (var i = 0; i < ul.childElementCount; i++) {
        var li_text = ul.children[i].textContent;
        var column = +li_text.split("_")[1].split(",")[1];
    }
```

Essentially I have a bunch of list elements that has some information in the format `text_numberX,numberY` and in this particular case I would like to extract `numberY` from all the list elements.
Here is my unordered list:

```
<ul id="coordinateList" style="visibility:hidden;height:0;overflow:hidden"></ul>
```

The list elements are loaded in like so:

```
public getGridCoordinates(){
    var table: string;
    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            table = data;
        }
    });
    var ul = document.getElementById('coordinateList');
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.id = table.split(";")[i];          // this?
        li.textContent = table.split(";")[i]; // or this?
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

The value 6 is just an example - it's actually a dynamic value.
Don't worry about how each list element is extracted, just note that each one has the format described above.

I've checked the html list using the DOM explorer, and the list elements seems to hold the right data. A console.log in the getGridCoordinates also returns the right data.
So I have no problem loading in the data, but extracting it later from JavaScript is what is troubling me; more specifically the line `var li_text = ul.children[i].textContent;`.

Here is an example of some data received by my ajax request:
'text1_1,1;text2_1,3;text3_2,2;text4_2,1;text5_1,2;text6_2,3'

Comment: I've thrown in some console.log's and it seems to load the data nicely - exactly because it is asynchronous, but I'll try anyway. I'll update the post with an example of the received data.

Comment: *Remove `async: false` - it is horrendous practice to use it.* Instead you should place your code in the `success` block as the AJAX call is asynchronous. It's also hard to debug any potential errors in your code as you haven't given us an example of the data being returned by your AJAX request.

Comment: I was under the impression that because it is asynchronous, I am able to do exactly that, but I think your way is more optimal anyway - it doesn't fix my issue though.

Comment: Obviously I meant 'synchronous' as that is what I have in my code ;)

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include an example of the data returned in your AJAX request.

Comment: Thank you. Is the `ul` empty to start with? I don't see the reason for the `for (var i = 0; i < ul.childElementCount; i++) {` line.

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry It isn't actually ul.childElementCount in my real code, I just changed it all to make an example, forgot it isn't actually that ;)
It's actually a dynamic value that could be 6 just to give an example.

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear on exactly what you're trying to do, but this makes some logical sense I hope: https://jsfiddle.net/o2jk25h2/

Comment: Yes, but I have all that working already. The problem is that I can't seem to extract the id's later on from JavaScript. Ultimately I want to figure out how many rows and columns to make, from what coordinates are in the data string. If the max coordinate is 3, I want to make 3 columns. It's the `var li_text = ul.children[i].textContent;` that's failing

Comment: are you sure can call `.children` on that `var ul = document.getElementById('coordinateList');` ???  `$( "#coordinateList li:nth-child("+i+")" ).text()` should work ! https://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/o2jk25h2/1/

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick unfortunately.